# how can i use php email function on vmware ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email

my ubuntu server is installed on vmware on win7. i want to use the php mail function as a test purpose.i couldn't find a solution yet.i dont want to receive emails but i just need to use the php mail function to send simple administration stuff like "email verification" , "reset password" etc.  How & What do you recommend me to do ?

Comment: Migrate/dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175488/test-phps-mail-function-from-localhost

Answer (score 3):

Honestly? 
I'd start by never using the mail() function, as it's [fundamentally](http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection) [broken](http://hostbaby.org/wiki/PHP_mail_exploit), and doesn't have a very feature-rich functionality.

Instead, use http://swiftmailer.org/.  Seriously, it'll give you the flexibility to do more secure emailing, and give you more scope in the future when you're refactoring the spaghetti.

Alternatively, if you wanna be really web2.0 and not have to touch the mailing process yourself, you can use a service like [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/docs/User%20Guide/index.html).  You could then [use their Web API](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code%20Examples/php.html) instead of using SMTP, and not have to even use Postfix/Exim/(other MTA of your choice).

There's yet another option, which is to install a dummy MTA, like [ssmtp](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/SSMTP), which only handles relaying mail, and then you can use any one of a number of SMTP providers or relay services.

Best not to handle the actual mail delivery yourself.  It's a pain in the butt, and is far better to just let someone else worry about it.  Like Sendgrid, or [AuthSMTP](http://www.authsmtp.com), or [Dyn Email](http://dyn.com/email/)